# problem in refreshing the page after making two ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, yahoo

**Problem** I am making ajax call to server1 i.e. csce and once I got the response I am sending the response as contents to server2 i.e.yahoo server after getting response from there I want to refresh the page or atleast redirect it to the same page. Both ajax calls are working fine. The contents I am sending are also saved the only problem is that I have to manually refresh the page to see the changes. I want to refresh the page once the contents are saved on yahoo. I tried **reload** and **redirect** commands in success function of yahoo. But nothing works. I can see the both ajax calls in the HTTPfox but not the redirect.

The url from which i am making calls is different from the url where contents are saved thats why I need to refresh the page to see the changes. i.e. I am saving in yahoo/save while sending contents and seeing changes at yahoo/edit.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Here is my code I am using. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong. If my problem is not clear kindly do ask me to clarify more. Thanks.

This code is the code:

```
 function handleButtonClick()
{
// Declare the variables we'll be using
var xmlHttp, handleRequestStateChange;

   // Define the function to be called when our AJAX request's state changes:
handleRequestStateChange = function()
{
    // Check to see if this state change was "request complete", and
    // there was no server error (404 Not Found, 500 Server Error, etc)
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200) 
    {
        var substring=xmlHttp.responseText;

        alert(substring);// I am able to see the text which is returned by the server1 i.e csce
var handleSuccess = function(o)
 {
   if(o.responseText !== undefined)
   {
     console.log(o.responseText);
 **window.location.reload()** // also I tried to redirect it to the same site but that also not works


  }
 };
var callback ={ success:handleSuccess,  failure: function(x) {
console.error(x) }, argument: ['foo','bar']};
var request = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST','http://yahoo.com******', callback, substring);

    }
}

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://cse*****id=c6c684d9cc99476a7e7e853d77540ceb", true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;
xmlHttp.send(null);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to display the content in your page? Why don't you try something along the lines of `document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;`?

With divID being the id of a div that you want to fill the content with.

Comment: Yes, if you're using AJAX, use it. Don't reload your page, just repopulate your content area.

Comment: Thanks Chris and aptwebapps:: I want to refresh the page to see the changes since the web page have different uri than the one where i am saving. And I have no way of controlling the changes. The changes i want to show to user is just by refreshing the page. Then it will automatically show the pictures. can you suggest any other wayout?

Comment: If you want the content on a separate page, you're going to have to pass the data somehow either with cookies, session variables, database, etc. If you're using AJAX and refreshing, it's kind of defeating the purpose. Anything you can elaborate on to make exactly what you're doing more clear may be helpful.

Comment: @Chris Thanks. Yes I am also feeling the same that refreshing defeats the purpose of ajax but even redirect also is not working.... I want to display the graphs which will be saved in yahoo since the user need see the new changes I need to refresh the page so that he can see the changes made by ajax. The url where call is made is different from the one which is used for display... but the domain is same i.e yahoo.com. Any ideas how to successfully do this. Kindly suggest... thanks for the concern...

Comment: Is there anyway to include the AJAX that pulls the content on the same page that displays it? Are the graphs being saved once you receive the AJAX data, or do you mean that the graphs will be saved by the user? Why do you need separate pages? Maybe you could provide sample code for the display page too?

Comment: @ Chris: Thanks for continuing the discussion. This part is crucial for my project. The graphs are saved on yahoo server so for accessing them i need to refresh the page. Since these are ajax calls they will just change on server.so I need to access the server again by refreshing to see changes on screen.

Comment: Why don't you just have a separate AJAX call to the graphs on the server after they have been updated? Then, you won't need to refresh the page.

Comment: If you can't avoid separate pages, how have you tried redirecting? Did you use something like: document.location='http://yahoo.com';

Answer (score 0):

try following in the `handleRequestStateChange` function

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```