# Is there a way to refresh the entire page after making a ajax call

Tags: ajax

Can I refresh the whole page after making ajax calls. kindly check my code on this link for details. Actually I am saving on different server and I am making calls from different url and to see the changes refreshing the page is a must. Kindly let me know if you need more details.

[problem in refreshing the page after making two ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173305/problem-in-refreshing-the-page-after-making-two-ajax-calls)

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ problem in refreshing the page after making two ajax calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173305/problem-in-refreshing-the-page-after-making-two-ajax-calls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No point in using AJAX if you are just going to refresh instantly after. Might as well just POST and let it do the refresh there. I realize this is what was said on the other thread but it's because it makes sense. For whatever reason though, if you still want to refresh, try using the jQuery AJAX call and in your success function just do `window.location.reload()`, that should work.

Answer (score 2):

check out my answer

[problem in refreshing the page after making two ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173305/problem-in-refreshing-the-page-after-making-two-ajax-calls/4198190#4198190)